# Angular JS: Why is my click event firing twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code. It loops over JSON to produce a nested ul list. I have a click event that executes the function toggleNav() bound to a anchor tag. I don't know why the click event is bound twice to the element. Also I am new to angular, is there a document that explains this concept out there? Thanks!

```
define([
'/assets/angularapp/AppDirectives.js',
'highstock'
], function (directives) {
directives.directive('collection', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",    //declare by element
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            collection: '='
        },
        template: "<ul class=\"nav nav-list tree\"><member ng-repeat=\"member in collection\" member=\"member\"></member></ul>"
    }
})

directives.directive('member', function ($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            member: '='
        },
        template: "<li ng-show=\"member.open\"><span><input type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"member.selected\" class=\"sideChkbox\"><a class=\"tree-toggle\" ng-click=\"toggleNav()\"><i class=\"icon-chevron-right\"></i>{{member.data}}</a></span></li>",
        controller: function($scope, $element){
            $scope.toggleNav = function(){
                angular.forEach($scope.member.children,function(child,key){
                    if(child.open==true){
                        alert("a")
                        child.open=false;
                    } else {
                        child.open=true;
                        alert("b")

                    }

                })

            }
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (angular.isArray(scope.member.children)) {
                 element.append("<collection collection='member.children'></collection>");
                $compile(element.contents())(scope)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you throw together a fiddle showing this, I don't see anything obvious that should be triggering two calls to the handler.  But being able to inspect the DOM after using the directives may lead to some insight.  Also are you sure you're not just getting multiple iterations of your loop within the handler it is in fact calling the handler multiple times?

Comment: Are you talking about the foreach loop triggers two alerts? It maybe the collection contains two elements, but the function is still bound once.

Comment: I made a fiddle to check out the issue, I see exactly what you're saying and honestly no idea why it's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/rEz52/1/

Comment: Only time I've had that happen was when I accidentally included app.js twice on the page - nothing similar happening?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out what is happening. The member directive is inside of a loop. So the click function is getting bound to all the li elements in every iteration. So the latest li will get one click bound to it, but the prior one will have a second click bound to it, and so forth. I am thinking to bind to a unique id to avoid the duplicate binding. Again, I am new to angular I am thinking theres a better way to do this.

Comment: The API reference and Developer Guide on the angularJS site is your friend, the documentation there is really good. For example, read the part about directives: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is because you are compiling the element.contents(), including the <a> with ng-click, which should be already compiled. At the time you call a manual compile, it gets compiled again.

you can fix it by this:

```
    ...
    if (angular.isArray(scope.member.children)) {
        var newMemEL = angular.element("<collection collection='member.children'></collection>");
        element.append(newMemEL);
        $compile(newMemEL)(scope);
    }
    ...
```

It looks like you are trying to create a treeview, in this case, it would be better to use [ngInclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude) instead of creating custom directives, have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QnwLnM?p=preview), note that it will not work with Angular 1.2.0rc1 due to this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3584)

Answer (score 2):

@Mr.DucNguyen's answer is correct, but if you don't want to further manipulate the DOM, you can approach it another way.

Flag the element as completed during the link function, so when it tries to link again it fails.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    // stop an already linked element from continuing
    if (element.attr('collection-linked')) {
        return;
    }
    // otherwise, add a completed flag to this element
    element.attr('collection-linked', true);

    // continue your linking ...
}
```